# AngularJS - Purpose of Writing $scope Before function($scope)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope

I started learning AngularJS by seeing few examples in Google, but no where explained about this one. So far i went through few examples where they have written the controllers like

```
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {

   $scope.text = 'Hello, Angular fanatic.';

});
```

But in few other blogs they are including '$scope' before function($scope)

```
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

   $scope.text = 'Hello, Angular fanatic.';

}]);
```

Is there any difference ? not only $scope, adding other dependencies too in the similar way.

Comment: This question is answered in the Angular docs.

Comment: You can find answers for all questions in Google and their corresponding API, why stackoverflow ? why given -2 to my questions.   Who is the admin for this stackoverflow ?

Answer (score 2):

Read the section on `A note on minification`.

https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05

In short, both ways of declaring dependencies are the same. The array notation is used so that minifier won't minify the dependencies and angular would know exactly what to fetch.

If you don't minify your code, you can use either way for dependency injection.

Answer (score 2):

There is indeed. Writing `['$someInjectable', function ($someInjectable)` is what we call 'minification proofing'. Some post-compiler will come along and minify your javascript, garbling your variables into cryptic a, b, c, ... etc. Internally, AngularJS inspects `function ($scope)` to determine that this function needs to receive a handle to `$scope`. If you minify the code, variables names are lost, but literals remain constant. The array-chain syntax is a way to make sure that angular can determine that `function (a, b)` is actually `function ($scope, $element)`.